# How to install dotnet framework 4.7.1 into docker container

Tags: .net, windows, docker

I want to install dotnet framework 4.7.1 into my windows10 machine

But while running the build process
I'm getting error
Error:.net framework/v4.7.1/Microsoft visual studio.qualitytools.unittestframework.winmd,but it doesn't exist

Can anyone help me in this case.![getting this issue while running the build process] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYnyk.jpg)

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.x/4.8 are already built into Windows 10, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10#net-framework-48 so you don't need to install anything separately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.